# How float number 0.0f represented in memory

Tags: floating-point

I know that decimal numbers are represented in floating point format.
every float represented as m2^e where m is mantissa and e is the exponent.

But am not able to find the 0.0f representation.Please provide the steps to get the 0.0f memory representation.

Answer (score 5):

0, inf, nan, are special values, since their mantissa and exponent cannot be derived. They have defined bit patterns:

```
 0 = 0 00000000 00000000000000000000000
-0 = 1 00000000 00000000000000000000000
```

See e.g. http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)FloatingPoint.html

Comment: You don't actually have to treat 0 as a special value: It's possible to interpret it as the denormal value with mantissa 0.

Comment: You should probably mention that you're specifically describing the IEEE 754-2008 binary32 interchange format. There are many different floating-point formats, with different choices about how to represent 0.